# gnome 3 top panel shadow

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I have a question about the top panel in gnome 3. I'm new to linux and want to remove the inner shadow of the top panel that appears when a window gets near the top panel. I use ubuntu 18.04. do you guys know how I can remove that shadow shown in the picture under here:

[image: with shadow]

I want it to look like the picture under here even when a window is near the top panel like in the picture above.

[image: without shadow]

Comment: Hi, i didn't see any difference.. can you point out me in rite direction..